# When I'm selecting a range how do I refer to the first selected cell of it and the last selected cell of it on VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

For example, let's say that I select the range A1:F1 in Excel.

In VBA, how do I refer specifically to the cell A1, to the cell F1 and to all the other cells that are within the range?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can `For Each` as already shown and also use the `.Cells` property of the `Range` object and specify the row and column within the range to retrieve.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim aRange As Range
    Set aRange = [A1:F1]

    Debug.Print aRange.Cells(1, 1).Address
    Debug.Print aRange.Cells(1,  aRange.Columns.Count).Address   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the cells in a selection:

```
For each myCell in ActiveSheet.Selection
    'Do something to the cell here
Next myCell
```

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be an ideal time when Selection can provide the information you require.

```
sub FirstLastFull()

    with selection

        debug.print "first cell is: " & .cells(1, 1).address(0,0)
        debug.print "last cell is: " & .cells(.rows.count, .columns.count).address(0,0)
        debug.print "full range is: " & .address(0,0)

    end with

end sub
```

The above will work on a contiguous range of selected cells. If you want the same information from a non-contiguous range, the Areas property must be considered.

```
sub FirstLastFull()

    with selection

        debug.print "first cell is: " & .cells(1, 1).address(0,0)
        with .areas(.areas.count)
            debug.print "last cell is: " & .cells(.rows.count, .columns.count).address(0,0)
        end with
        debug.print "full range is: " & .address(0,0)

    end with

end sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what `.address(0,0)` adds to the output?